# What's the value of $c$ that makes $|x - 3| < 1 \Rightarrow |x + 5| < c$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my Calculus lecture, we were given the following exercise to solve in class:

> Find the value of $c$ that makes $|x - 3| < 1 \Rightarrow |x + 5| < c$ true.

This is what I came up with:

$$\begin{align*}
|x - 3| &< 1  \\
|x - 3| \frac{|x + 5|}{|x - 3|} &< 1 \frac{|x + 5|}{|x - 3|} \\
|x + 5| &< \phantom{1}\frac{|x + 5|}{|x - 3|} \end{align*}$$

Therefore,

$$c \geq \frac{|x + 5|}{|x - 3|}$$

Is this the right approach?

(This question is not for marks, it's just an exercise. We took most of them up, but I think we skipped this one.)

Comment: you can plot the range of $x$ on a number line. $|x-3|$ represents the distance of a point $x$ from the point $3$; similarly $|x+5|$ or $|x-(-5)|$ represents the distance of point $x$ from the point $-5$. Edit: This is the same as @Hongyi Huang's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|x-3|<1$

$-1<x-3<1$

$2<x<4$

$2+5<x+5<4+5$

$7<|x+5|<9$

So, $c \ge9$

Answer (score 3):

$c$ should be a constant. And $|x-3|<1$ implies $2<x<4$. Now compute the distance between $x$ and $-5$, we have $7<|x+5|<9$.